# BUILD FAILED ...while creating War file in jenkins using ant script

Tags: java, xml, maven, ant, jenkins

I have added **build.xml** in root directory of java project checkedin in svn successfully.

Now, Following is Console output of jenkin build

1. Copying
   /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/FinalWar/WebContent/WEB-INF/web.xml to
   /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/FinalWar/build/WebContent/WEB-INF/web.xml
2. File copy complete. war:Creating WAR file ...**Then**
3. BUILD FAILED /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/FinalWar/build.xml:39:
4. Deployment descriptor:
   /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/FinalWar/build/WEB-INF/web.xml does not
   exist.*

My question is while copying[step 1] web.xml it is getting copied to **build/WebContent/WEB-INF/web.xml**

But while creating War why it is searching[step 4] for **/build/WEB-INF/web.xml**

Answer (score 0):

Check the path.. you are copying it to build/WebContent/WEB-INF and tried reading from build/WEB-INF ... correct the path of reading by including WebContent.

Comment: I am not copying or reading the path...
Jenkins copying it to build/WebContent/WEB-INF/web.xml 
and while creating War tries to read it from /build/WEB-INF/web.xml

Comment: I mean in your script .. change the path where it is reading web.xml

Comment: But Now i m getting this error  this /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/FinalWar1/build/WEB-INF/lib does not exist.



this is my code part of creation of war

<target name="war" depends="build">
<echo message="Creating WAR file ..." />
<war destfile="${distDir}/${warFileName}" webxml="${buildDir}/WebContent/WEB-INF/web.xml">
<fileset dir="${buildDir}" />
<lib dir="${buildDir}/WEB-INF/lib" />
<classes dir="${buildDir}/WEB-INF/classes" />
</war>
<echo message="WAR file created." />
</target>


In output it is not coping the lib folder why is that so ??

Comment: Same thing .. change the path to include WebContent as your lib is in build/WebContent/WEB-INF/lib

Answer (score 0):

First, you need to decide if this is a Jenkins issue or an issue with the build itself.

1. Does it build on your machine. If it doesn't, your build itself has a problem.
2. If it builds on your machine, do the following:

   1. Disable the project that's building. You don't want Jenkins to suddenly start building while you're playing around.
   2. In Jenkins, there's a workspace folder in that project. Go into that folder and see if `FinalWar/build/WebContent/WEB-INF/web.xml` actually exists. If not, you may have an error in your build.xml itself. If it does...
   3. Log into the Jenkins server.
   4. Go into the Jenkins Home directory, then `jobs`, then the project name, then `workspace`. This is where Jenkins is running the build.
   5. Try doing the build here. You may have to set your `$PATH` to pick up the correct version of Ant and the JDK you want to use.

Jenkins doesn't do anything unusual with the build. It run Ant just like you would from the command line. In fact, if you look at the Console output, you'll even see the command line Jenkins used.

There can be issues with builds failing in Jenkins, but not on your command line. Normally, you'll see Jenkins declare a `BUILD SUCCESSFUL` only to declare it failed a few lines later. This is usually due to a misconfigured post build process -- for example, you attempt to archive an artifact that doesn't exist, or display a test result from a XML file that doesn't exist.

Most of the time, failed Jenkins builds are due to the build itself having problems, and not doing exactly what you want. The first thing when a build fails is to do a ***CLEAN*** checkout on your local machine, and try a build. If that works, try running the build from the `workspace` on the Jenkins build server itself.

And, before you play around with the workspace on the build server, disable the Jenkins project (and don't forget to reenable it after you finished). This way, Jenkins isn't messing up the workspace while you're analyzing what went wrong.